# Getting video url from Tumblr Api

Tags: python, video, tumblr, pytumblr

Im working with a client project that can allow downloading videos.

Now im using interactive console for testing ideas;

Here is the command for getting response about last 2 videos on dashboard;

```
client.dashboard(limit=2, offset=0, type='video')
```

and its response that i get from tumblr like;

```
{u'posts': [{u'liked': False, u'followed': True, u'reblog_key': u'QXToPeMK', u'video_url': u'https://vt.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh.mp4', u'short_url': u'https://tmblr.co/ZWX3Ye2LCLbAo', u'can_send_in_message': True, u'thumbnail_width': 632, u'is_nsfw': False, u'player': [{u'width': 250, u'embed_code': u'\n<video  id=\'embed-59075d73d2510751819830\' class=\'crt-video crt-skin-default\' width=\'250\' height=\'142\' poster=\'https://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_smart1.jpg\' preload=\'none\' muted data-crt-video data-crt-options=\'{"autoheight":null,"duration":12,"hdUrl":false,"filmstrip":{"url":"https:\\/\\/68.media.tumblr.com\\/previews\\/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_filmstrip.jpg","width":"200","height":"113"}}\' >\n    <source src="https://cevizlihelva.tumblr.com/video_file/t:b2DBOMjQ63RxQF8fAIVl4w/160194515634/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh" type="video/mp4">\n</video>\n'}, {u'width': 400, u'embed_code': u'\n<video  id=\'embed-59075d73d2510751819830\' class=\'crt-video crt-skin-default\' width=\'400\' height=\'228\' poster=\'https://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_smart1.jpg\' preload=\'none\' muted data-crt-video data-crt-options=\'{"autoheight":null,"duration":12,"hdUrl":false,"filmstrip":{"url":"https:\\/\\/68.media.tumblr.com\\/previews\\/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_filmstrip.jpg","width":"200","height":"113"}}\' >\n    <source src="https://cevizlihelva.tumblr.com/video_file/t:b2DBOMjQ63RxQF8fAIVl4w/160194515634/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh" type="video/mp4">\n</video>\n'}, {u'width': 500, u'embed_code': u'\n<video  id=\'embed-59075d73d2510751819830\' class=\'crt-video crt-skin-default\' width=\'500\' height=\'285\' poster=\'https://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_smart1.jpg\' preload=\'none\' muted data-crt-video data-crt-options=\'{"autoheight":null,"duration":12,"hdUrl":false,"filmstrip":{"url":"https:\\/\\/68.media.tumblr.com\\/previews\\/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_filmstrip.jpg","width":"200","height":"113"}}\' >\n    <source src="https://cevizlihelva.tumblr.com/video_file/t:b2DBOMjQ63RxQF8fAIVl4w/160194515634/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh" type="video/mp4">\n</video>\n'}], u'duration': 12, u'id': 160194515634L, u'post_url': u'http://cevizlihelva.tumblr.com/post/160194515634/babyanimalgifs-this-video-is-sacred', u'can_reply': True, u'display_avatar': True, u'source_title': u'babyanimalgifs', u'tags': [], u'blog': {u'share_likes': True, u'updated': 1493654842, u'description': u'Seni de seviyorum ama bir Urfa kebap de\u011filsin\xa0', u'title': u'CevizliHelva', u'url': u'http://cevizlihelva.tumblr.com/', u'can_message': True, u'placement_id': u'', u'uuid': u'cevizlihelva.tumblr.com', u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'header_full_height': 343, u'title_color': u'#000000', u'header_bounds': u'12,490,282,11', u'title_font': u'1785 GLC Baskerville', u'link_color': u'#000000', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/9f95f7e8c8205180162647222c61e328/uvoiyri/ritoov8s5/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_8azaggwnhvk0k8kskg80wg0g8_focused_v3.gif', u'show_description': True, u'header_full_width': 500, u'header_focus_width': 479, u'header_stretch': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/9f95f7e8c8205180162647222c61e328/uvoiyri/y5Woov8s4/tumblr_static_8azaggwnhvk0k8kskg80wg0g8_2048_v2.gif', u'avatar_shape': u'circle', u'show_avatar': True, u'header_focus_height': 270, u'background_color': u'#8c8988', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/9f95f7e8c8205180162647222c61e328/uvoiyri/y5Woov8s4/tumblr_static_8azaggwnhvk0k8kskg80wg0g8.gif'}, u'avatar': [{u'url': u'https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_3fe2daddc99d_30.png', u'width': 30, u'height': 30}, {u'url': u'https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_3fe2daddc99d_64.png', u'width': 64, u'height': 64}], u'key': u'KbAoJwN0u', u'share_following': False, u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'cevizlihelva'}, u'recommended_source': None, u'state': u'published', u'reblog': {u'comment': u'', u'tree_html': u'<p><a href="http://babyanimalgifs.tumblr.com/post/160174918173/this-video-is-sacred" class="tumblr_blog">babyanimalgifs</a>:</p>\n<blockquote><p>This video is sacred</p></blockquote>'}, u'html5_capable': True, u'type': u'video', u'recommended_color': None, u'format': u'html', u'timestamp': 1493654784, u'note_count': 1888, u'video_type': u'tumblr', u'source_url': u'http://babyanimalgifs.tumblr.com/', u'trail': [{u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'babyanimalgifs', u'share_likes': False, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'header_full_height': 342, u'title_color': u'#444444', u'header_bounds': u'0,734,342,126', u'title_font': u'Gibson', u'link_color': u'#529ECC', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/99fffdfec9505720b4f4862e65f14b67/jy7vcat/kPko1e42d/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_2po76ntom7swkws0wwggwk0wc_focused_v3.jpg', u'show_description': True, u'header_full_width': 1024, u'header_focus_width': 608, u'header_stretch': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/99fffdfec9505720b4f4862e65f14b67/jy7vcat/zwQo1e42c/tumblr_static_2po76ntom7swkws0wwggwk0wc_2048_v2.jpg', u'avatar_shape': u'square', u'show_avatar': True, u'header_focus_height': 342, u'background_color': u'#FAFAFA', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/99fffdfec9505720b4f4862e65f14b67/jy7vcat/zwQo1e42c/tumblr_static_2po76ntom7swkws0wwggwk0wc.jpg'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'babyanimalgifs.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>This video is sacred</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160174918173'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>This video is sacred</p>', u'is_root_item': True}], u'date': u'2017-05-01 16:06:24 GMT', u'can_like': True, u'thumbnail_height': 360, u'slug': u'babyanimalgifs-this-video-is-sacred', u'blog_name': u'cevizlihelva', u'summary': u'This video is sacred', u'caption': u'<p><a href="http://babyanimalgifs.tumblr.com/post/160174918173/this-video-is-sacred" class="tumblr_blog">babyanimalgifs</a>:</p><blockquote><p>This video is sacred</p></blockquote>', u'thumbnail_url': u'https://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_op8w7keI1Y1uvv5gh_frame1.jpg', u'nsfw_score': 0, u'can_reblog': True}, {u'liked': True, u'followed': True, u'reblog_key': u'mkcfsKFT', u'video_url': u'https://vt.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn.mp4', u'short_url': u'https://tmblr.co/Z4Z7wf2LCLagS', u'can_send_in_message': True, u'thumbnail_width': 480, u'is_nsfw': False, u'player': [{u'width': 250, u'embed_code': u'\n<video  id=\'embed-59075d73e0f7f940137481\' class=\'crt-video crt-skin-default\' width=\'250\' height=\'141\' poster=\'https://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_smart1.jpg\' preload=\'none\' muted data-crt-video data-crt-options=\'{"autoheight":null,"duration":58,"hdUrl":false,"filmstrip":{"url":"https:\\/\\/68.media.tumblr.com\\/previews\\/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_filmstrip.jpg","width":"200","height":"112"}}\' >\n    <source src="https://blogreenroom.tumblr.com/video_file/t:q66PEVa9GIcU21xq6DMAtg/160194513564/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn" type="video/mp4">\n</video>\n'}, {u'width': 400, u'embed_code': u'\n<video  id=\'embed-59075d73e0f7f940137481\' class=\'crt-video crt-skin-default\' width=\'400\' height=\'225\' poster=\'https://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_smart1.jpg\' preload=\'none\' muted data-crt-video data-crt-options=\'{"autoheight":null,"duration":58,"hdUrl":false,"filmstrip":{"url":"https:\\/\\/68.media.tumblr.com\\/previews\\/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_filmstrip.jpg","width":"200","height":"112"}}\' >\n    <source src="https://blogreenroom.tumblr.com/video_file/t:q66PEVa9GIcU21xq6DMAtg/160194513564/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn" type="video/mp4">\n</video>\n'}, {u'width': 500, u'embed_code': u'\n<video  id=\'embed-59075d73e0f7f940137481\' class=\'crt-video crt-skin-default\' width=\'500\' height=\'281\' poster=\'https://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_smart1.jpg\' preload=\'none\' muted data-crt-video data-crt-options=\'{"autoheight":null,"duration":58,"hdUrl":false,"filmstrip":{"url":"https:\\/\\/68.media.tumblr.com\\/previews\\/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_filmstrip.jpg","width":"200","height":"112"}}\' >\n    <source src="https://blogreenroom.tumblr.com/video_file/t:q66PEVa9GIcU21xq6DMAtg/160194513564/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn" type="video/mp4">\n</video>\n'}], u'duration': 58, u'id': 160194513564L, u'post_url': u'https://blogreenroom.tumblr.com/post/160194513564/tekboynuzlutimsah-keskelerolmasakeskee', u'can_reply': True, u'display_avatar': True, u'source_title': u'yavbsgaq', u'tags': [], u'blog': {u'share_likes': False, u'updated': 1493654857, u'description': u'G\xf6n\xfcl d\xfc\u015ft\xfc\u011f\xfc yerde g\xfczel', u'title': u'', u'url': u'https://blogreenroom.tumblr.com/', u'can_message': True, u'placement_id': u'', u'uuid': u'blogreenroom.tumblr.com', u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'regular', u'title_color': u'#C5BBA7', u'header_bounds': u'', u'title_font': u'1785 GLC Baskerville', u'link_color': u'#F9FDFF', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/67888d3bef1e929a6685f1f4d34fe6cb/besgmp9/YlRoghs3a/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.gif', u'show_description': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'header_stretch': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': False, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/67888d3bef1e929a6685f1f4d34fe6cb/besgmp9/YlRoghs3a/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.gif', u'avatar_shape': u'circle', u'show_avatar': True, u'background_color': u'#222222', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/67888d3bef1e929a6685f1f4d34fe6cb/besgmp9/YlRoghs3a/tumblr_static_filename.gif'}, u'avatar': [{u'url': u'https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0830e1091627_30.png', u'width': 30, u'height': 30}, {u'url': u'https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0830e1091627_64.png', u'width': 64, u'height': 64}], u'key': u'0Bs7njfK4', u'share_following': False, u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'blogreenroom'}, u'recommended_source': None, u'state': u'published', u'reblog': {u'comment': u'', u'tree_html': u'<p><a href="https://tekboynuzlutimsah.tumblr.com/post/160187732397/keskelerolmasakeskee-vejeteryan-zombiee" class="tumblr_blog">tekboynuzlutimsah</a>:</p><blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://keskelerolmasakeskee.tumblr.com/post/160187306029/vejeteryan-zombiee-rumeysalak" class="tumblr_blog">keskelerolmasakeskee</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://vejeteryan-zombiee.tumblr.com/post/160187248166/rumeysalak-meselenemesala-demonvoice" class="tumblr_blog">vejeteryan-zombiee</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://rumeysalak.tumblr.com/post/160186794948/meselenemesala-demonvoice" class="tumblr_blog">rumeysalak</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://meselenemesala.tumblr.com/post/160186559832/demonvoice-sureklisureksizlik" class="tumblr_blog">meselenemesala</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://demonvoice.tumblr.com/post/160132304136/sureklisureksizlik" class="tumblr_blog">demonvoice</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://sureklisureksizlik.tumblr.com/post/159945807058/meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi-mesneviiiden" class="tumblr_blog">sureklisureksizlik</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote>\n<p><a href="http://meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi.tumblr.com/post/159945770212/mesneviiiden-ders-ald%C4%B1%C4%B1%C4%B1mm" class="tumblr_blog">meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p>Mesneviiiden ders ald\u0131\u0131\u0131mm</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>20.saniyeden sonra kapatamiyorsun</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>Belli bir s\xfcreden sonra hipnoz oluyorsun</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>Ya bu ne aksjsjhdjakshfhskdh</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>Lan \xe7ok g\xfczel dkwpa\u015fmdls</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>Beynim y\u0131kand\u0131 diskdisocf\u015fkf</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>MESNEV\u0130 DEN DERS ALDI\u011eIMMMM</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p>5 saniye bak\u0131nca ders aliyosunuz</p>\n</blockquote>'}, u'html5_capable': True, u'type': u'video', u'recommended_color': None, u'format': u'html', u'timestamp': 1493654779, u'note_count': 852, u'video_type': u'tumblr', u'source_url': u'https://yavbsgaq.tumblr.com/post/159457857872/mesneviden-ders-alan-\xe7ocuk', u'trail': [{u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi', u'share_likes': False, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'header_full_height': 883, u'title_color': u'#888888', u'header_bounds': u'259,669,635,0', u'title_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'link_color': u'#000000', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/784ec57104a28ff6c576b3e740a06166/vej79pw/uf0ooxaby/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_filename_focused_v3.jpg', u'show_description': True, u'header_full_width': 669, u'header_focus_width': 669, u'header_stretch': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/784ec57104a28ff6c576b3e740a06166/vej79pw/A1hooxabw/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.jpg', u'avatar_shape': u'square', u'show_avatar': True, u'header_focus_height': 376, u'background_color': u'#000000', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/784ec57104a28ff6c576b3e740a06166/vej79pw/A1hooxabw/tumblr_static_filename.jpg'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>Mesneviiiden ders ald&#305;&#305;&#305;mm</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'159945770212'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>Mesneviiiden ders ald\u0131\u0131\u0131mm</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'sureklisureksizlik', u'share_likes': False, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'regular', u'title_color': u'#1900ff', u'header_bounds': u'', u'title_font': u'Streetscript', u'link_color': u'#0400ff', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/7b13417ca885518e257e41ff6868165f/ygqj350/Hfyog9eox/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.jpg', u'show_description': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'header_stretch': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/7b13417ca885518e257e41ff6868165f/ygqj350/Hfyog9eox/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.jpg', u'avatar_shape': u'circle', u'show_avatar': True, u'background_color': u'#FAFAFA', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/7b13417ca885518e257e41ff6868165f/ygqj350/Hfyog9eox/tumblr_static_filename.jpg'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'sureklisureksizlik.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>20.saniyeden sonra kapatamiyorsun</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'159945807058'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>20.saniyeden sonra kapatamiyorsun</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'demonvoice', u'share_likes': False, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'header_full_height': 1136, u'title_color': u'#000000', u'header_bounds': u'363,640,662,108', u'title_font': u'Georgia', u'link_color': u'#FFC664', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/7d010026e490cc0afad536632f6bb38a/tpicygu/AAvop7yht/tumblr_static_tumblr_static__focused_v3.png', u'show_description': True, u'header_full_width': 640, u'header_focus_width': 532, u'header_stretch': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/7d010026e490cc0afad536632f6bb38a/tpicygu/ryvop7yhr/tumblr_static__2048_v2.png', u'avatar_shape': u'square', u'show_avatar': True, u'header_focus_height': 299, u'background_color': u'#2C0709', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/7d010026e490cc0afad536632f6bb38a/tpicygu/ryvop7yhr/tumblr_static_.png'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'demonvoice.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>Belli bir s&uuml;reden sonra hipnoz oluyorsun</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160132304136'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>Belli bir s\xfcreden sonra hipnoz oluyorsun</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'meselenemesala', u'share_likes': True, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'regular', u'header_full_height': 316, u'title_color': u'#888888', u'header_bounds': u'25,523,308,20', u'title_font': u'Capita', u'link_color': u'#000000', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/c16cc9cf7f43f6caf51aed75bea31411/xtomshc/5wTop12dw/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_5kfyeiej5n8c0k8kg0wkggww_focused_v3.png', u'show_description': True, u'header_full_width': 539, u'header_focus_width': 503, u'header_stretch': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/c16cc9cf7f43f6caf51aed75bea31411/xtomshc/9GYop12du/tumblr_static_5kfyeiej5n8c0k8kg0wkggww_2048_v2.png', u'avatar_shape': u'circle', u'show_avatar': True, u'header_focus_height': 283, u'background_color': u'#fff200', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/c16cc9cf7f43f6caf51aed75bea31411/xtomshc/9GYop12du/tumblr_static_5kfyeiej5n8c0k8kg0wkggww.png'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'meselenemesala.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>Ya bu ne aksjsjhdjakshfhskdh</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160186559832'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>Ya bu ne aksjsjhdjakshfhskdh</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'rumeysalak', u'share_likes': False, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'header_full_height': 1280, u'title_color': u'#000000', u'header_bounds': u'157,719,561,0', u'title_font': u'1785 GLC Baskerville', u'link_color': u'#000000', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/48f1855360206c3cc0c7e53e77f13c7c/j9t5gzu/br6omqug6/tumblr_static_tumblr_static__focused_v3.png', u'show_description': True, u'header_full_width': 719, u'header_focus_width': 719, u'header_stretch': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/48f1855360206c3cc0c7e53e77f13c7c/j9t5gzu/y1Uomqug2/tumblr_static__2048_v2.png', u'avatar_shape': u'square', u'show_avatar': False, u'header_focus_height': 404, u'background_color': u'#E9CCDE', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/48f1855360206c3cc0c7e53e77f13c7c/j9t5gzu/y1Uomqug2/tumblr_static_.png'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'rumeysalak.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>Lan &ccedil;ok g&uuml;zel dkwpa&#351;mdls</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160186794948'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>Lan \xe7ok g\xfczel dkwpa\u015fmdls</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'vejeteryan-zombiee', u'share_likes': True, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'regular', u'title_color': u'#5D00F9', u'header_bounds': u'', u'title_font': u'Streetscript', u'link_color': u'#9B1AF6', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/95db5dd654d25ba696729294be82b97e/uivucxh/WbEookc1y/tumblr_static__2048_v2.gif', u'show_description': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'header_stretch': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/95db5dd654d25ba696729294be82b97e/uivucxh/WbEookc1y/tumblr_static__2048_v2.gif', u'avatar_shape': u'circle', u'show_avatar': True, u'background_color': u'#60CAE0', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/95db5dd654d25ba696729294be82b97e/uivucxh/WbEookc1y/tumblr_static_.gif'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'vejeteryan-zombiee.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>Beynim y&#305;kand&#305; diskdisocf&#351;kf</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160187248166'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>Beynim y\u0131kand\u0131 diskdisocf\u015fkf</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'keskelerolmasakeskee', u'share_likes': True, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': True, u'is_nsfw': True, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'title_color': u'#EEEEEE', u'header_bounds': u'', u'title_font': u'Gibson', u'link_color': u'#000000', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/bdeaf5464fec733e341c68f500b74860/14xyr5n/9iKoodaq6/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.gif', u'show_description': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'header_stretch': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/bdeaf5464fec733e341c68f500b74860/14xyr5n/9iKoodaq6/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.gif', u'avatar_shape': u'circle', u'show_avatar': True, u'background_color': u'#170432', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/bdeaf5464fec733e341c68f500b74860/14xyr5n/9iKoodaq6/tumblr_static_filename.gif'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'keskelerolmasakeskee.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>MESNEV&#304; DEN DERS ALDI&#286;IMMMM</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160187306029'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>MESNEV\u0130 DEN DERS ALDI\u011eIMMMM</p>'}, {u'blog': {u'can_be_followed': True, u'name': u'tekboynuzlutimsah', u'share_likes': True, u'share_following': False, u'is_adult': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'theme': {u'title_font_weight': u'bold', u'title_color': u'#ff03bc', u'header_bounds': u'', u'title_font': u'Sofia Pro', u'link_color': u'#ff00bf', u'header_image_focused': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/ed32b034805a0d0945d6c26308eb2637/minltpe/mcmofx4lr/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.png', u'show_description': True, u'show_header_image': True, u'header_stretch': True, u'body_font': u'Helvetica Neue', u'show_title': True, u'header_image_scaled': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/ed32b034805a0d0945d6c26308eb2637/minltpe/mcmofx4lr/tumblr_static_filename_2048_v2.png', u'avatar_shape': u'square', u'show_avatar': True, u'background_color': u'#da89d9', u'header_image': u'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/ed32b034805a0d0945d6c26308eb2637/minltpe/mcmofx4lr/tumblr_static_filename.png'}, u'active': True, u'uuid': u'tekboynuzlutimsah.tumblr.com'}, u'content': u'<p>5 saniye bak&#305;nca ders aliyosunuz</p>', u'post': {u'id': u'160187732397'}, u'content_raw': u'<p>5 saniye bak\u0131nca ders aliyosunuz</p>'}], u'date': u'2017-05-01 16:06:19 GMT', u'can_like': True, u'thumbnail_height': 270, u'slug': u'tekboynuzlutimsah-keskelerolmasakeskee', u'blog_name': u'blogreenroom', u'summary': u'Mesneviiiden ders ald\u0131\u0131\u0131mm', u'caption': u'<p><a href="https://tekboynuzlutimsah.tumblr.com/post/160187732397/keskelerolmasakeskee-vejeteryan-zombiee" class="tumblr_blog">tekboynuzlutimsah</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://keskelerolmasakeskee.tumblr.com/post/160187306029/vejeteryan-zombiee-rumeysalak" class="tumblr_blog">keskelerolmasakeskee</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://vejeteryan-zombiee.tumblr.com/post/160187248166/rumeysalak-meselenemesala-demonvoice" class="tumblr_blog">vejeteryan-zombiee</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://rumeysalak.tumblr.com/post/160186794948/meselenemesala-demonvoice" class="tumblr_blog">rumeysalak</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://meselenemesala.tumblr.com/post/160186559832/demonvoice-sureklisureksizlik" class="tumblr_blog">meselenemesala</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://demonvoice.tumblr.com/post/160132304136/sureklisureksizlik" class="tumblr_blog">demonvoice</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://sureklisureksizlik.tumblr.com/post/159945807058/meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi-mesneviiiden" class="tumblr_blog">sureklisureksizlik</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p><a href="http://meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi.tumblr.com/post/159945770212/mesneviiiden-ders-ald%C4%B1%C4%B1%C4%B1mm" class="tumblr_blog">meteerpeginyaridasonensigarasi</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p>Mesneviiiden ders ald\u0131\u0131\u0131mm</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>20.saniyeden sonra kapatamiyorsun</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>Belli bir s\xfcreden sonra hipnoz oluyorsun</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>Ya bu ne aksjsjhdjakshfhskdh</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>Lan \xe7ok g\xfczel dkwpa\u015fmdls</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>Beynim y\u0131kand\u0131 diskdisocf\u015fkf</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>MESNEV\u0130 DEN DERS ALDI\u011eIMMMM</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>5 saniye bak\u0131nca ders aliyosunuz</p></blockquote>', u'thumbnail_url': u'https://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_oo992rdQT51udslsn_frame1.jpg', u'nsfw_score': 0, u'can_reblog': True}]}
```

so i define

```
dashboard_response = client.dashboard(limit=2, offset=0, type='video')
```

Here is the problem now how can i get every video url, sender username etc from that bulk data of course i dont set limit on "2" at real client. so i need a solition for at least "20"

i need something like this;

```
video1_url= videourl
video1_sender_username= username1
video2_url= videourl2
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually i found the way

```
dashboard_response['posts']["int number of the post you get"]['video_url'])
```

Sample - you want to get url of first video;

```
dashboard_response['posts'][1]['video_url'])
```